# I can't view files in emacs above line 30

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I have recently installed emacs for mac osx and inside of the GUI. When I open files the the buffer is totally blank. When I duplicate the buffer using C-x 2, then I can see my buffer in the copied buffer. It's very annoying to have to hack open the original buffer each time I use the GUI! Does anyone else have this problem? Perhaps it is some setting inside of .emacs.d that I need to change? I'm currently still on yosemite.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you add some screenshots or clarify in some other way? Also, which version of Emacs did you install, and by which method? Does this happen if you launch Emacs with `emacs -Q`, bypassing your configuration files?

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for the feedback! Yes, `emacs -Q` solves the issue, I will troubleshoot my config files. I am using emacs version 24.5 installed from a `.dmg` file from [emacsformacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/). Am learning to use emacs while learning clojure. I began learning clojure with [clojure for the brave and true](http://www.braveclojure.com/).